# Dynamic <HR /> In Flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, flexbox

I have this application I'm working on it has a simple layout (which I was able to achieve).
But, there's this 1 weird requirement I need to achieve and I've spent 2 days trying to get it working and alas, I need some help.

This is the current HTML I have: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6refmLxo/12/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="row flex-container">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 4</label>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 6</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 7</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 8</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flex-item {
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 8px); 
}
    .flex-container {
  width: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}
    .flex-container hr {
        width: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Now, this is the layout I want (as shown in that JSFiddle Link).
As you can see, there are 2 rows and there's an HR tag separating them.
Now, if I am to remove a value from row 1, the element of row 2 should shift up to row 1.

Both the rows should have maximum 4 elements. So, if I remove 1 element from row 1, only 1 element should move up to row 1 and so on.

And if there's no element in row 2, that HR shouldn't even be shown.

What I think can be done is like, getting the number of elements I have in the rows and then put in an "ngIf" on HR based on that count. But, that still doesn't solve the first requirement I have of shifting the elements above.

I'm literally stuck onto this one. How am I supposed to move on with this one? Some guidance would be appreciated. I don't need the exact code, maybe some thinking on how can I achieve that... that's what I need help with.

Comment: can you paste your ngfor source code too. ? (you just need to add a logic on index of for loop that index is ===4 then add hr

Comment: unfortunately, there's no `ngFor` loop. The html is hardcoded like that and values come and are used just like that. If I had a loop, it would've been amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem you can solve using flex Order.

Steps:

- Add a common class for all items without 'HR'
- write a CSS code for all item use "nth-of-type(2)" [learn about nth-of-type()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)
- parent must the display flex and flex wrap.
- write css for HR 100% width.

It's better if you maintain the order CSS using inline CSS.

#Here the code snippet or visite [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yav3862h/)

```css
.flex-item {
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 8px); 
}
.flex-container {
  width: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) { order: 1 ; }
.item:nth-of-type(2) { order: 2; }
.item:nth-of-type(3) { order: 3; }
.item:nth-of-type(4) { order: 4; }
.item:nth-of-type(5) { order: 5; }
.item:nth-of-type(6) { order: 6; }
.item:nth-of-type(7) { order: 7; }
.item:nth-of-type(8) { order: 8; }

.flex-container hr {
    order: 5;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row flex-container">
    <div class="item col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 4</label>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="item col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 6</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 7</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-sm-3" style="margin:5px">
      <label>Label 8</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

==== Thanks ====

Comment: This one worked amazingly and that `nth-of`type()` was something new and good read. It definitely saved me a lot of work that I would've done with arrays and all. However, if I remove all elements of row 1, row 2 gets shifted above. But, the HR tag still comes. I think that's something I will need to look into. But, everything else worked like a charm. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Xonshiz, then you needed a simple javascript code just check minimum item if the condition is not full then you remove/hide the <hr />. hopefully, this is work to solve your problem.

Comment: Yep, I did that. Thanks a lot again! :D

Answer (score 1):

I did it just with CSS, forked your snippet, basically modified your css a bit, you were close to the answer:

```
.flex-item {
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 8px); 
}
    .flex-container {
  width: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
    .flex-container hr {
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     height: 2px;
     border: none;
     background-color: #000;
     position: absolute;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 10px);
  max-width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3k84p7to/

Comment: Thanks for this one, it worked good separately. However, in my codebase it was causing some issues of elements not shifting properly. @Abu's answer worked amazingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this:

```js
const items = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5', 'Label 6', 'Label 7', 'Label 8'];

const firstRow = items.slice(0, 4);
const secondRow = items.slice(4);

document.body.innerHTML = `${firstRow.join(',')} <hr /> ${secondRow.join(',')}`;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this approach. But, I'd rather avoid any extra array maintenance for now. Check @Abu's answer. That stays completely within CSS and HTML properties and get the job done nicely. However, thanks for this approach as well.